# Apache Nifi - issues with file listing path filter

Tags: apache-nifi

I have sub directory YYYYMMDD which is created by system on daily basis and I need to list file using Nifi  file listing. So how can I modified path filter to recognise subdirectory (YYYYMMDD) and read file quickly i tried with Java reg exp language but still files scanning slow and taking much time Thanks for help.

Path filter of Nifi file listing can retrieve files form  YYYYMMDD (ex- 20230831) subdirectory.

Comment: You could use the following to get the current date part `${now():format('yyyyMMdd')}` 
`now` function returns the current date and time. Using the `format` you manipulate it to the format that you require in your case `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: Which processor(s) are you using?